# Block element after a float element ignores margin-top property

Tags: html, css

I have a `h1`, `img` and `div` tag in a div tag. The img tag I have assigned a `float: left;`. And the div tag a `clear: both;`. Since I want to have a space between the image and the div tag, I have also assigned a margin-top to the div tag.

**Problem:** However, the margin is not interperated.

**Question:** Why is that? And what do I have to do to insert a space?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: black;
}

.block {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flow-root;
}

.block img {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  
}

.leftFloat {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.user-interaction-btns {
  margin-top: 20px; /* this margin doesnt work, why? */ 
  display: flex;
  clear:both;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>Title lorem ipsum </h1>
  <img class="leftFloat" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
  
  <div class="user-interaction-btns">
    <button>Action</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: add the margin to the image as a margin-bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the margin top does not refer to the image but to the text above. An easy fix for your problem would be to add a margin-bottom: 10px; to the image.

Comment: Correct, if you remove `clear: both;` your button div will sit below the text and `margin-top` would be applied.

Comment: @ShaneMuirhead That would be right. But I suspect the questioner wanted it below the text image block.

Comment: Then I would advise the questioner to not use float and to use a better method altogether. i.e flex

Comment: @ShaneMuirhead I always find flex solutions good. However, there is nothing to be said against float. Although I have noticed recently that some people think that float should no longer be used. I haven't yet read an argument why you shouldn't use it. I haven't actively looked for one now either. Maybe you could tell me why you should use flex instead of float?

Comment: sure, flexbox is supported by all web browsers and gives you the layout benefits of floats but with more control over responsiveness and it's mobile friendly not to forget there is no need to do strange hacks to prevent stuff like what the questioner is getting.

Comment: @MaikLowrey — Flex is designed to arrange content in rows or columns. Float is designed to allow a block, typically an image, to be wrapped in text and for subsequent text to flow up beside it *even if its in a different block element*. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin . So you think that float is wrong for the above case of positioning an image in the text? I remembered that float replaced alignment.

Comment: Float doesn't replace text-align. They do completely different things.

Answer (score -1):

Floating Elements is old and comes with some quirks and hacks. Flex-box was introduced in 2009 and is now support by all web browsers, it's responsive and mobile friendly. It has all the benefits of float but without having to implement hacks. Below I have swapped from your float approach and used flex instead.

```css
.img-text-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.user-interaction-btns {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>Title lorem ipsum </h1>

 <div class="img-text-container">
    <img class="leftFloat" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <div class="text">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
    </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="user-interaction-btns">
    <button>Action</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```